# Stop count timediff after meet the criteria

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code

```
select no1, visit, DATE1, TIME1, STATUS ,hour(diff) * 60 + minute(diff) as diff from( 
select no1, visit, DATE1,

if(
@active or STATUS in ('Pending Active') and STATUS not in ('Stop Clock') ,
timediff(addtime(DATE1,TIME1),@prevTime),0) as diff,

time(@prevTime := addtime(DATE1,TIME1)) as time1,
@active := STATUS in ('Pending Active') and STATUS not in ('Stop Clock'),STATUS from detail,

(select @prevTime :=0,@active :=false) as init where NO_LOG = '03/12/008' and visit = 'On Site Visit' order by no1) as final
```

and the result will be like this :

```
+------+--------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
| no1  |    visit     |    DATE1   |  TIME1  |   STATUS          | diff|
+------+--------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
|74030 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |19:23:00 | Pending           |  0  |
|74031 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |19:44:00 | Pending           |  0  |
|74032 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:40:00 | Pending Active    |  56 |
|74033 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:45:00 | Pending Active    |  5  |
|74034 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:50:00 | Pending Active    |  5  |
|74035 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:54:00 | Active            |  4  |
|74036 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |21:30:00 | Close             |  36 |
```

but what i want if visit = On Site Visit and STATUS = Pending Active (1st Pending Active) then all deff below 1st Pending Active will be '0' (zero)..like example below

```
+------+--------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
| no1  |    visit     |    DATE1   |  TIME1  |   STATUS          | diff|
+------+--------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
|74030 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |19:23:00 | Pending           |  0  |
|74031 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |19:44:00 | Pending           |  0  |
|74032 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:40:00 | Pending Active    |  56 |
|74033 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:45:00 | Pending Active    |  0  |
|74034 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:50:00 | Pending Active    |  0  |
|74035 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |20:54:00 | Active            |  0  |
|74036 |On Site Visit | 2012-03-12 |21:30:00 | Close             |  0  |
```

maybe someone can help me.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't come up with the query at the moment, but my solution would be using `UNION ALL` and filter with `WHERE Status =` and having the second (or third) `UNION` group have value 0 on `diff`.

**Code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT no1, visit, DATE1, TIME1, STATUS, 0 AS diff
        FROM detail
        WHERE status IN ('Pending') AND NO_LOG = '03/12/008' AND visit = 'On Site Visit'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT no1, visit, DATE1, TIME1, STATUS, # do the diff calculation here
        FROM detail
        WHERE status IN ('Pending Active') AND NO_LOG = '03/12/008' AND visit = 'On Site Visit'
        LIMIT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT no1, visit, DATE1, TIME1, STATUS, 0
        FROM detail
        WHERE status IN ('Pending Active', 'Active', 'Close') AND NO_LOG = '03/12/008' AND visit = 'On Site Visit'
        LIMIT 1, 9999) AS h
ORDER BY no1 ASC
```

[Info about UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: thx Robin. Maybe someone can give me some query example..kinda confuse :p

Comment: Well to be modest the way you presented diff calculation confused me aswell :p Maybe this update will help?